# Coding weighted mean (R)

Tags: r, weighted-average

I am having trouble with a piece of my code. I want to perform a weighted mean but the value I get is not the value I obtain if I calculate the weighed mean myself.

Here's how I'm coding the weighted mean:

```
weighted.mean(x = dataset$A[rows], weights = weights)
```

The variable is "dataset$A" and the rows I'm using for the weighted mean are listed in "rows" (there are 2 rows). The weights are listed in "weights."

Here's how I'm calculating it myself:

```
dataset$A_MEAN[rows[1]]*weights[1] + dataset$A_MEAN[rows[2]]*weights[2]
```

Why is there a difference with these two lines of code? 
I tried with the following values:

```
dataset$A = [45792.76, 64984.67] 
weights = [0.3253927, 0.6746073]
```

The first line of code returns: 55388.71
The second line of code returns: 58739.76

Thank you so much! I am sure that this is something minor, but it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Note that R is vectorized, your sum can be written `sum(dataset$A[rows] * weights)`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your use of `weighted.mean`

The arguments `weights` should be `w`:

`weighted.mean(x = dataset$A[rows], w = weights)` should give you what you want.

When calling a function, you can make sure that you're using the correct variable names by reading the function's documentation with `?weighted.mean`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much! So, if I were to feed the function into a sapply function, I would also write it with a "w", right? For instance:
 new_values <- sapply(oes16[rows,8:22], weighted.mean, w = weights, na.rm = T)

Comment: No problem. Also, for reference, if this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.